# How to get row details of MySql table just after that row inserted to an Android App

Tags: android, mysql

I want to get the column values of a row to a specific android app* after a new row is inserted to a mysql database table in my server.

specific android app* - we identify each app uniquely by phone number.

table structure as follows.

id       fromphonenumber       clientphonenumber       messagebody 
1            +3434354546                   +484844646245               test123

when this kind of row inserted, I want to get the messagebody column value to the app like the way normal sms appear.
Can you please explain a way to do it and suggest any tutorial to refer.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Could you please provide an example and a code snippet showing what you have tried so far? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen sir for replying quickly. Actually I don't know any method to do this task.
I thought about after a trigger fires run a php script , but it's not the way to do this.

Comment: Then I though about time to time look for new updates on the table and download new row details. but to do it I have to run a background service and it's consume phone resource.
So currently I don't know any way to do this.
Thank you in Advance

Comment: Ok. If I understand what you are asking, I would suggest encapsulating your database in a content provider, and then use a content observer to be notified of changes to your database. A google search of either of these term will come up with plenty of tutorials on the subject. Hope that helps.